# Repeating pixels vertically in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

Using GLES2.0 I am trying to create point sprites that 'clamp' the texture downward or upward based on the lowest/highest pixel values of a shape after transforming it. It's shape is dependent on the current angle (uniform for all sprites), its radius and depth (vertex attributes).

I've successfully implemented the desired effect however it performs slow, and I know there must be a simpler way to do it.

In essence what I want is when the sprites y value is below a threshold (defined by its shape), it simply copies the color of the previous pixel downward until it reaches a second threshold.

This shadertoy example shows the effect and how I've currently implemented it (The bottom function in particular)

[Shadertoy Example. Use the mouse to move the shape](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/llGcDR)

As you can see, the pixels are repeated downward/upward regardless of the shapes orientation - whatever is at the bottom of the rounded rectangle (or rectangle or circle - dependent on the 'r' constant) is simply copied. 
My method was to use a piecewise function that calculates the edge of the shape after it has been transformed. The shape will always be a rounded rectangle with a radius from 0 (A rectangle) to 1 (a circle).
Unfortunately this requires a lot of calculations.

I have tried changing the values that don't depend on 'x' to values in the vertex shader that then get passed into the fragment shader so they only need be calculated per-vertex - however there was literally no change in performance (Props to GL's compiler optimizations)

For reference, ~100 of these point sprites are drawn on screen at a time - the vertex attributes for each are the position, radius, depth, and an offset co-ordinate for the texture atlas. In the shadertoy example only one texture is used.

How can this effect be implemented more efficiently? (Either within the shader itself or using other OpenGL functionality) Would writing and then reading those bottom pixels to a 1D texture be faster? Is there any way to manipulate the color buffer to repeat a color downward? I feel that changing the shape to a squircle rather than a rounded rectangle would allow for calculating the bottom edge faster, however I want to have the option to use squares, circles and everything inbetween, and personally I'm sure that the method of finding the bottom edge then getting the texture (regardless of the formula that defines the bottom edge) is less efficient that some method to copy the pixels downward or upward if there is no value below or above.

Edit: Whether to repeat upward or downward is dependent on the angle as seen in the example, but the process would obviously be the same.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help

Comment: Can you just create a polygonal mesh to represent your rounded cuboid, and apply a texture to it which has point filtering?

Comment: @Columbo I'll be honest, that's beyond what I'm capable of at the moment, I'm really only able to work with quads and point sprites. If It can't be done without having to use a 3D mesh I'll have to deal with the performance hit